# How to diagnose ownership errors and fix them?

Tags: rust, tauri

I just wanted to read file contents from a user picked file and save them to a var.
Unfortunately I am getting Ownership Errors, but I dont know how to pass a mutable Reference to the function I'm calling in the following code:

```rust
use tauri::api::dialog::FileDialogBuilder;

#[tauri::command]
fn import_file() -> String {

    let mut file_contents = String::new();
    let mut file_name = String::new();

    FileDialogBuilder::new()
        .set_title("Select a file to import")
        .pick_file(|file_path| {
            // do something with the optional file path here
            // the file path is `None` if the user closed the dialog
            if let Some(file_path) = file_path {
                println!("{}", file_path.to_string_lossy().into_owned());
                let contents = std::fs::read_to_string(file_path).unwrap();
                file_contents = contents;
            }
        });

    println!("{}", file_contents);

    return String::from("yoo");
}
```

I tried wrapping the expression in a block and assigned it to the var like
`file_contents = { FileDialogBuilder::new()...`
but got errors again.

I tried to cargo-expand the main.rs but got unreadable binary code. Seems to come from tauri.

Comment: It's really hard to debug errors we don't even see, please [edit] your question and provide the full error messages you're getting. This is also not showing the way you're running your function, you should provide a **reproducible** [mre].